# add_filter for where statment issue

Tags: menus, filters

I am trying to get start and end dates for posts filtered, and I found the documentation for the 'posts_where' filter, I am just testing it so far, but when ever I add the filter, it seems to pull in the loop data for the main navigation (i.e. from wp_nav_menu())

I added:

```
<?php remove_filter('posts_where', 'uc_filter_where'); ?>

<?php wp_nav_menu(array('sort_column' => 'menu_order', 'menu_class' => 'nav', 'theme_location' => 'primary-menu')); ?>
```

in an attempt to clear out the where filter for the posts, but no such luck. Anyone explain to me what I am doing wrong.

Comment: So you've got a `uc_filter_where` function that you only want to use on the main query? Or only for certain post type queries?

Comment: Well, actually, I want to customize the taxonomy query. This occurs in the 'taxonomy.php'. I tried posting screenshots, but my measly reputation of 1 won't let me post images to the forum. Anyhow, when I add the filter, I get results including navigation items (an undesired result), when I use the default query it gives me what I want, but I need the custom query for filtering date ranges. Here's my function.php code:

Comment: function _filter_where($where = "") { 
        $where .= " AND post_date BETWEEN '" . $_GET[POSTS_START_DATE_NAME] . "' AND '" . $_GET[POSTS_END_DATE_NAME] . "'";
 
            return $where;
    }

        add_filter('posts_where', 'filter_where');`

Comment: This is the SQL string produced when the filter is added: `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.* FROM wp_posts  INNER JOIN wp_term_relationships ON (wp_posts.ID = wp_term_relationships.object_id) WHERE 1=1  GROUP BY wp_posts.ID ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10`. Where '1=1'?????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first of all you'll want to make sure that you want to and your `WHERE` clause in. `posts_where` will fire for (almost) every query so you want to be sure that you're adding it to the right one. This can be done with the use of [conditional tags](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags).

***Note:** The `WHERE 1=1` is added because it means a valid `WHERE` expression is added, and can be extended using the `posts_where` filter (i.e by just adding `AND X=Y` ). Infact WordPress hardcodes the `WHERE` and adds in the conditionals - so it needs something to be there to be sure that the SQL query is valid*

```
add_filter('posts_where', 'wpse55985_posts_where',10,2);
function wpse55985_posts_where($where, $query){
    global $wpdb;

    //$query is a WP_Query object

    if( $query->is_main_query() && is_tax('my-tax') ){
         //This is the main query for the 'my-tax' taxonomy page

         if( isset($_GET[POSTS_END_DATE_NAME]) && isset($_GET[POSTS_START_DATE_NAME]) ){
             //Variables are set.
             $start = $_GET[POSTS_START_DATE_NAME];
             $end = $_GET[POSTS_END_DATE_NAME];

             //Append our additional 'WHERE' clause
             $where .= $wpdb->prepare(
                 " AND {$wpdb->posts}.post_date BETWEEN %s AND %s ", $start,$end
             ) ;
         }
    }
    return $where
}
```

#### Explanation

1. First of all use `is_main_query()` to check that this is the query that is the 'main' query for the page. The [conditionals](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) all relate to this main query. So I'm checking that this is the main query, and the query is for the taxonomy 'my-tax' - in particular that the 'my-tax' taxonomy page is being viewed. So the above should only filter posts on the `my-tax` taxonomy page. See [`is_tax()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_tax). Otherwise, we just return the `$where` clause without doing anything.
2. Check that the `$_GET` variables you are after are set. You should really be registering custom query variables and using the `$query->get()` method than dealing with `$_GET` directly. If they aren't set, we don't alter the query.
3. Use the `$wpdb` class to get the post table name and to safely prepare the query. See [this Codex page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb), and the last part of [this article](http://wp.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creative-coding/data-sanitization-and-validation-with-wordpress/). This part is vital to protect yourself form SQL injection.

Please note, I've not tested this, and there could be syntax errors.

Comment: First off, Stephen, thank you very much for you concerted effort. I don't think I've ever gotten such a great response in a help forum, like yours. Unfortunately, that approach produced the same results (i.e. a broken query)

Comment: I am under the suspicion that this is resetting the entire query where statement. Because attachments as well as menu items are showing up in the results along with the posts.

Comment: Stephen, nevermind, your code was kosher, it was a syntax goof on my part. I forgot to add the 3rd and 4th parameter to the filter method. Works like a charm =) Thanks so much!